# In Clojure, can a default value be provided while using sequential destructuring?

Tags: clojure, destructuring

Seems like providing a default value in Associative destructuring is well documented. https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring

Any known way to supply a default value in sequential destructuring?

For instance:

```
    (let [[hey you guys] ["do" "re"]]
      (println hey)
      (println you)
      (println guys))

Output:
do
re
nil
```

How would you provide a default value for 'guys'?

Have tried

```
(let [[hey you (or guys "me")] ["do" "re"]]

(let [[hey you #(or % "me")] ["do" "re"]]
```

and a few variations of

```
(let [[hey you guys :or "me"] ["do" "re"]]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No I don't believe there is a way to offer default values in non-associative destructuring.

There would be more than one way to accomplish that, depending on what you're after. The closest to the snippets you provide might be:

```
(let [input ["do" "re"]
      defaults ["def1" "def2" "def3" "def4"]
      [hey you guys] (concat input (drop (count input) defaults))]
  (println hey you guys)) ;; do re def3
```

If you only have a default value for the 3rd arg, then you can use:

```
(let [[hey you guys] (conj ["do" "re"] "def3")]
  (println hey you guys)) ;; do re def3
```

or

```
(let [[hey you guys] ["do" "re"]
      guys (or guys "def3")]
  (println hey you guys)) ;; do re def3
```

Comment: This isn't a bad solution.  Though the gymnastics you have to do to join the input and defaults together is unfortunate. I really only have a need for one default though, which would have been easy to provide through the associative destructuring interface.  Was hoping there was a way to almost force the list into an associative paradigm so its superior interface could be used.

Comment: @darktrek added alternatives

Answer (score 1):

You can find a good overview of Clojure destructuring here:

http://blog.brunobonacci.com/2014/11/16/clojure-complete-guide-to-destructuring/

You can get what you want with a simple function:

```
(defn apply-defaults
  [vals defaults]
  (vec (map-indexed
         (fn [idx val-default]
           (or (get vals idx) ; replaces both missing and `nil` values
             val-default))
         defaults)))
```

with result:

```
data      => [:a     nil    :c]
defaults  => [:def-a :def-b :def-c :def-d]

(apply-defaults data defaults) => [:a :def-b :c :def-d]
```

Note that you have to modify it if you want to retain any `nil` values in the input.

Answer (score 1):

If the length is short, you can do this:

```
(let [[hey you guys] (merge defaults values)]
      (println hey)
      (println you)
      (println guys))
```

Merge is a function that you must define/choose depending on the behaviour that you want, it will probably be one of these two (as in the previous answers):

1. Overwrite the values in `defaults` that are present in `values`
2. `concat` the values from the first one missing